# Azure DevOps: Is it possible to select deployment agent at release creation

Tags: deployment, azure-devops, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline, agent

I currently have a release pipeline with a number of stages.  In the `Deployment group job` I have to specify `Deployment group` (which is fine), but in order to run my pipeline on a specific VM(agent) in that group I also have to specify some tags to limit the number of matching targets.

Instead of using tags in the `Deployment group job` I would like to use a variable to specify which VM(agent) to use. This variable can then be set when the release is created. Is this something that can be achieved in some way?

Comment: Are you using self-hosted agents or microsoft-hosted?

Comment: They are microsoft hosted.

Comment: Why then do you want to select which agent perform the deploy?

Comment: Ideally, I would like to control this through a variable in the pipeline that is "settable at release time". The reason for this is that I am forced to use a deployment group with VMs that are not all the same. I can only use a few of them for this particular pipeline. I know this is not how it is supposed to work, but as a workaround I am curious to know if there is a way to do this.

Comment: But why, I mean you don't control the infrastructure and then you don't mind which agent performs the deploy. It doesn't make any sense, I would understand it if you have self-hosted agents, but no with Microsoft hosted ones.

Comment: An agent is connected to a VM. And the VMs require some special setup in order for me to run my pipeline. This setup has not been done on all the VMs in this deployment group so I would like to be able to control this by using a variable. I can, of course, edit the pipeline every time I want to run it and change the tags but it would be easier with a variable.

Comment: And I think I misunderstood the difference between self-hosted and Microsoft-hosted. I am pretty sure that we have self-hosted agents. We manage VMs and everything. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Ok, then  I will answer a way to do this through agent capabilities

Comment: For what it is worth, it seemed like an unimportant question on self-hosted vs. microsoft hosted.  The question is regarding deployments and I can't think of a scenario where you would be using a release pipeline that was NOT a self-hosted agent.  Especially considering we're talking specifically about deployment agents.

Comment: What is the scenario for why you want to deploy to one VM (agent) instead of another at release time?

Comment: @Matt I tried to explain my reason for wanting this in my previous comments. I am working in an organization that recently migrated to Azure DevOps and started focusing on test automation etc. The situation is still a little in experimenting mode regarding pipeline setup, test environment setup on VMs, etc. I am currently forced to use a deployment group with VMs where not all can be used for running a pipeline. This is a temporary situation, hopefully, but in the meantime, I was just curious to find out if there is a way dynamically select which VM to run on.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the only way to do this would be through Agent capabilities. 
In self-hosted agents a capability is:

> Capabilities are name-value pairs that are either automatically
>   discovered by the agent software, in which case they are called system
>   capabilities, or those that you define, in which case they are called
>   user capabilities.

Under your Agent pools if you select your agent you will discover a tab Capabilities.
For self-hosted, you could determine a user-defined capability. These means to have a capability you will later check during release time. 
How could you provide that info? In your YAML you will specify:

```
pool:
  name: Default
  demands: SpecialSoftware # Check if SpecialSoftware capability exists
```

What this will do is only agents that meet those capabilities will be suitable to perform the deploy

And remember this if anyone finds this answer, for Microsoft hosted agents:

> Demands and capabilities apply only to self-hosted agents. When using
>   Microsoft-hosted agents, you select an image for the hosted agent. You
>   cannot use capabilities with hosted agents.